# get another document data using StreamBuilder with flutter and Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

i'm trying to create a social app where the last chat rooms are displayed in the main page,
every ChatRoom document contains

> [lastSentMessage,lastSentMessageBy,LastsentMessageDate,Array of users
> who are chatting together]

so the problem i'm facing right now is when i use StreamBuilder to display those chat rooms in a custom widget that i have built to hold every chat room data individually(it displays name of user who sent the message , and his profile photo and lastSentMessage) the StreamBuilder actually display the lastSentMessage like charm but i'm always getting the same data for the displayname and photo url,

here is the code :

```
  String phone;
  QuerySnapshot userDataByPhone;

  accessUserDataByPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) async{
   // userDataByPhone is a QuerySnapshot to access the document of the user where the phoneNumber matchs the given phoneNumber
    userDataByPhone = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").where("phonenumber",isEqualTo:phoneNumber ).get();
  }

  Widget buildMyChatRooms()
  {
    getChatRoomsStream();

    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: chatRoomsStream,
      builder: (context,snapshot ){
        if(snapshot.hasData) {
          return ListView.builder (
              itemCount:snapshot.data.docs.length,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {

                DocumentSnapshot doc = snapshot.data.docs[index];
                phone = "+"+doc.id.replaceAll(loggedUser.phoneNumber.substring(1), "").replaceAll("_", "");
                accessUserDataByPhoneNumber(phone);
              return SingleChatRoomWidget(
                  userDataByPhone.docs[0]["displayname"],
                  doc["lastSentMessage"],
                  doc["lastSentMessageBy"],
                  userDataByPhone.docs[0]["photourl"]) ;
              }
          );
        }
        else{
```

it always returning the same data :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgpOv.jpg)

also here is my custom chat room code :

```
SingleChatRoomWidget(String name, String lastSentMessage,lastSentMessageBy,String profileUrl)
  {
    return Column(
      children: [
        SizedBox(height: 15,),
        Row(children: [
          Container(height: 65,width: 65,decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle,image: DecorationImage(image:NetworkImage(profileUrl),fit: BoxFit.cover),),),
          SizedBox(width: 8,),
          Column(children: [
            Text(name,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple,fontSize: 16,),),
            SizedBox(height: 7,),
            lastSentMessageBy==loggedUser.phoneNumber?Text("You: "+lastSentMessage,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45,fontSize: 16,),):
            Text(lastSentMessage,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45,fontSize: 16,),),
          ],)
        ],),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Container(height: 0.5,width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,color: Colors.black45,),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace both `0` to `index` here:

```
SingleChatRoomWidget(
              userDataByPhone.docs[0]["displayname"],
              doc["lastSentMessage"],
              doc["lastSentMessageBy"],
              userDataByPhone.docs[0]["photourl"])
```

To be like this:

```
SingleChatRoomWidget(
              userDataByPhone.docs[index]["displayname"],
              doc["lastSentMessage"],
              doc["lastSentMessageBy"],
              userDataByPhone.docs[index]["photourl"])
```

Comment: i have tried that and it gives me : RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1

Comment: Check if you  have more than 1 user stored in database, then if problem not there then its obvious that `userDataByPhone` is the problem so have to look how it is set up,  and don't forget it has to look up if it has data ready.